# JS - how to hook into success and error callbacks from a different file

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, promise

I have my JS set up as follows.

App1.js

```
function x(){
  thirdPartyLibrary.performAsyncTask((resultObject, errorObject) => {
    // This is a callback function, invoked when performAsyncTask is done.
    // I can handle resultObject and errorObject here.
  });
}
```

Let's say I have other files as part of this app. Each of them calls x(), and would invoke their own version of a handleSuccess() or handleError() function depending on the results of the call to x().

How can I structure the call to x() such that I can achieve this? It's almost like I want to "listen" to the results of performAsyncTask() from App1.js, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Either make `x` accept a callback or make it return a promise. Prefer the latter. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to stay with callbacks (due to very old JS clients or whatever), you can provide the callback as parameter to `x`:

```
function x(myCallback) {
  thirdPartyLibrary.performAsyncTask(myCallback);
}

// other file:
x((resultObject, errorObject) => {
  // handle just like before
});
```

You could even change it to two callbacks, depending on the result. Only one of your callbacks will be called in the end:

```
function x(successCallback, errorCallback) {
  thirdPartyLibrary.performAsyncTask((resultObject, errorObject) => {
    if (errorObject) return errorCallback(errorObject);
    else return successCallback(resultObject);
  });
}

// other file:
x(
  function handleSuccess(resultObject) {
    // handle success
  },
  function handleError(errorObject) {
    // handle error
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have `x` return a `Promise` that resolves with `resultObject` if there's no error, or rejects with `errorObject` if there is an error. Then, callers of `x` can chain `.then` onto the `Promise` to handle successes, and chain `.catch`es to handle failures:

```
function x(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    thirdPartyLibrary.performAsyncTask((resultObject, errorObject) => {
      if (errorObject) reject(errorObject);
      else resolve(resultObject);
    });
  });
}

x()
  .then(result => {
    // handle successful result
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle error
  });
```